# Checking a +1/+1 counter requirement

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Abzan Battle Priest](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Abzan%20Battle%20Priest) has an ability that reads

> Each creature you control with a +1/+1 counter on it has lifelink.

Does it grant lifelink to creatures with two +1/+1 counters?

Comment: What do you mean by "becomes a +2/+2"? Are you talking about cards like [Dauntless Onslaught](http://magiccards.info/ddn/en/27.html) that say a creature "gets +2/+2", or cards that put two +1/+1 counters on the creature?

Comment: @dopplegreener, First of all, he's clearly talking about Abzan Battle Priest since he copied the text verbatim, and there's nothing else remotely similar. So both the card and the question mentioned counters. Contrary to what you say, this is definitely a question about counters, whatever he meant by "becomes say a +2/+2". I have no problem editing an unanswereable question into a question whose answers answer his question whatever his question might be. He can always clarify or ask a followup question later. The sites of this network work better that way.

Comment: @doppelgreener, You seem to have stopped reading my comment halfway through.

Comment: @Ikegami: While you are correct that the question is clearly about *counters*, your edit loses an important distinction.  It is possible - likely even - that the asker and is confused by what happens if the creature has a single +2/+2 counter (for some reason), as opposed to two +1/+1 counters.  Answers to the question in its new form may not discuss that case.

Comment: @Tynam, I know. I explained that. You also seem to have stopped reading my comment halfway through.

Comment: @ikegami I read it.  I disagree: I don't think answers to the edit *will* answer his question.  We should close and request clarification - this situation is exactly what close-as-unclear is for.

Comment: @Tynam, *won't*? It *was*. Closing as unclear is a completely stupid alternative over actually answering the question. Nothing stopping the OP was clarifying if need be. Really guys, think for a second about what's best for everyone.

Answer (score 4):

A creature with two +1/+1 counters has a +1/+1 counter, so [Abzan Battle Priest](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Abzan%20Battle%20Priest)'s static ability will grant that creature lifelink.

Note that being granted +1/+1 and having a +1/+1 counter are very different. If you control [Dauntless River Marshal](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dauntless%20River%20Marshal), Abzan Battle Priest and an Island, the Marshal won't be granted Lifelink.